# Can Nginx decompress gzip file in response?

Tags: nginx, gunzip

**Question:**

Can Nginx decompress gzip file in response?

**What exactly?**

1. Request `curl 127.0.0.1/file.json.gz` should return decompressed json in response.

**More details:**

1. File exists `/path/file.json.gz`.
2. Nginx config:

```
server {
 location / {
        gunzip on;
        root   /path;
    }
}
```

3. Nginx build includes gunzip module http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_gunzip_module.html

```
nginx -V 2>&1 | grep "\-\-with\-http_gunzip_module" => ... --with-http_gunzip_module ...
```

4. Response is gzip encoded:

```
curl -v 127.0.0.1/file.json.gz
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> GET /index.html.gz HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx/1.13.1
< Date: Wed, 11 Mar 2020 20:41:59 GMT
< Content-Type: application/octet-stream
< Content-Length: 392
< Last-Modified: Tue, 31 Jan 2017 15:01:11 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
< ETag: "5890a6b7-188"
< Content-Encoding: gzip
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< 
���X�N�0
   ��+
```